# I frequently tweet on 2 topics. How can I not annoy followers only interested in one?

Tags: twitter

I am an activist/keyboard warrior. I tweet about two somewhat related topics - certainly related to each other for me, but not necessarily to my followers.

So I don't want to create two accounts for this, as I'm actually aiming for followers primarily interested in both topics, but I need follower numbers from the people that are only interested in one.

I know if I don't like someone else's tweet I can choose an option: **Show Less Often > This tweet is not relevant**. Will this enable users to hide one of my two topics? And how would I make sure it knows what tweets are on what topic?

Edit: note: this is not a duplicate of [Tweeting without annoying others](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67226/tweeting-without-annoying-others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hashtags are an option, and followers that dislike one topic can mute that tag entirely. It's a bit of a blunt move and requires you to tag each tweet appropriately, but it works.

```
Settings > Content Preferences > Muted > Muted Words
```

It's really unlikely that Twitter will pick up on your topics and offer them as mutable options for your followers, even if they go out of their way to mark the tweet as "not relevant."